# Can I say to my girlfriend "You are my whole"?

Tags: word-choice, complements, homophones

I want to say to my girlfriend that she is everything for me. And my question is if I can say her this thing by the sentence "You are my whole".

I made a little googling about but I didn't find a clear answer.

Comment: @Catija. I just wanted to know specifically if this option is considered as correct, of course that I have a lot of different options.

Comment: Then the answer is "no" it sounds wrong... and it **particularly** sounds wrong because the homophone with "hole"...

Comment: "You are my whole" sounds like  "You are my whore". Take care not to be misunderstood.

Comment: @QuoraFeans - Actually, it's worse than that. It sounds exactly like "You are my hole," which would be an astoundingly crude sexual reference.

Answer (score 14):

The more idiomatic expressions that you hear used are "You make me whole" and "You complete me".

Answer (score 8):

I had to think a bit about why that sounds funny to me.  While *whole* is indeed both an adjective and a noun, so there isn't anything grammatically wrong with the sentence, the question "your whole what?" comes to mind.  This is the reason for Subjunctive's comment.  While we see what you are driving at, we just don't say this.  She is your whole *something*, such as world or life.

Comment: As you said I also notice that is can be a noun (whole) and then there is no place for question, or at least it's not necessary since it's not an adjective.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but I think the answer should include Catija's observation above that "whole" and "hole" are homonyms so while the sentence makes sense in writing it will be badly misinterpreted if spoken.

Comment: @Readin There is that.

Answer (score 5):

"You complete me" would be very proper, but "You are my whole", based on the tendency of most to take things in a sexual nature might lead to you getting slapped...

Comment: There a few ways that "You are my whole" could be misinterpreted sexually:  "You are my hole", or "You are my whore", or "You are my ho."  ("You are my ho" means the same thing as "You are my whore", but in a very low-class dialect.)

Answer (score 4):

"You are my whole" is not an English idiom, nor is it a complete sentence.  Here are some similar poetic statements:

There is a [song](http://www.metrolyrics.com/you-are-my-everything-lyrics-98-degrees.html) titled

> You are my everything.

There is a popular country [song](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/kennychesney/theregoesmylife.html) whose refrain includes the lines:

> There goes my life.
>   My future, my everything.

And another popular [song](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/tonigonzaga/youaretheone368912.html)'s refrain includes the lines:

> you are the one
>   That I've been searching for my whole life through

In American culture, if a young man says something like this to his girlfriend, he is taking a big risk.  [Many women want a man who has a life of his own, and is not dependent on a particular woman for his happiness.](http://marriedmansexlife.com/take-the-red-pill/)  They appreciate it if they can make him happy -- but they might think less of him if he is not confident that he "can survive" "with or without" her.

Comment: Regarding to the risk :D I think that every woman would happy to hear such sentence, it's not necessary to understand from it that in fact that he depends on her like a boy after his mom. It's just a romantic attitude. :)

Comment: It depends how the woman is inclined to interpret any romantic statement. As one song goes, "If you can't live without me, why aren't you dead yet?" (Once you get to that point, you're probably beyond hope anyway.)

Comment: While I think your answer is fine, I think the romance advice is out of place. It's extremely context dependent, and we're here to help folks express themselves in English, not give relationship advice.

Comment: I'm not sure usage in song lyrics is a good guide. In this case, there happens to be a song from 1969 by the Poppy Family entitled "Which Way You Going Billy" that contains the lines "You are my whole, babe/My heart and my soul, babe". It was widely mocked at the time because the word "whole" sounds exactly like "hole", which has sexual connotations. I would find a different way to express the sentiment.

Answer (score 2):

In writing it sounds weird (because if she is "whole" it means that she's better off without you, so "my whole" makes no sense), and phonetically it's completely rude and vulgar.

I suggest you look for some other expression.  There are a few good ones in other answers.